# Is there a language that meets these criteria?

Tags: list-of-languages, miniature-artificial-languages

I feel less and less comfortable with the incoherence of natural languages, so I'm looking for a constructed language that suits me.

1. semantically close words must share a common affix (not like biology and mathematics in English which are sciences but do not have the same suffix),
2. vocabulary must be finite and relatively small (a few hundred or thousand words would be fine) with no synonyms,
3. grammar must be fully regular.

Comment: 2 and 3 — toki pona. 1 and 3 — esperanto.

Comment: Well, in Esperanto biology is biologio but mathematics is matematiko

Comment: I don't know Esperanto and frankly I don't like it. I prefer artlangs but not only a priori but a posteriori as well. So it was just a guess ;)

Comment: No worries. I don't think math is considered a science anyway.

Comment: It is considered as a formal science, that is not the topic anyway.

Comment: [Lojban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojban)?

Comment: Re: Lojban. 1) _Gismu_ (root words) do not have this property, though _fu'ivla_ (drives words) might. 2) There is a small set of _gismu_ and _cmavo_ (particles), but a potentially unbounded set of _fu'ivla_ which could include words that are four all-intensive porpoises synonyms. Though mistakes like the one in the previous sentence are supposedly impossible in Lojban, which lacks homophones and ambiguous phonology. 3) This definitely, though the grammar is truly unlike any other.

Comment: If two words share such an affix but are not “semantically close”, do they fail the criterion?  Can two meanings be close to a third but not close to each other?

Comment: I don't think the criteria would be broken in this case but it is certainly a thing to avoid. Well, I guess proximity is transitive.

Comment: Just in case you haven't seen Rosenfelder's page on the irregularities of Esperanto: https://www.zompist.com/kitespo.html

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be *toki pona*. Reasons:

> semantically close words must share a common affix (not like biology and mathematics in English which are sciences but do not have the same suffix)

In toki pona, every science has a compound noun word beginning from *sona*. Biology is *sona jan* and Mathematics is *sona nanpa*. (Physics is *sona lon* and Linguistics is *sona toki*.)

This is due to the fact that toki pona has a limited vocabulary; so, to form words like "physics", it simply says the phrase "science of existence" or *sona lon*.

> vocabulary must be finite and relatively small (a few hundred or thousand words would be fine) with no synonyms

The vocabulary is just 123 words. Almost all of these are polysemantic, there's nothing like synonyms.

> grammar must be fully regular

Grammar is not fully regular, but that's only because of the fact that toki pona has a few words. However, there are *not* that many exceptions, as in any language like English or Spanish. I have studied 12 lessons of the official book and till then, the only irregularity is the fact that *li* doesn't follow *mi* and *sina*.

**In all, the language satisfying (1) and (2) and partly (3) to its fullest is toki pona.**

Another close competitor is *Esperanto*. It totally satisfies (2) and (3) and partly (1). (Some semantically similar words don't seem to have common affixes in them.)

So, in all, if you are looking for such a language, go definitely for **toki pona** or **Esperanto**.

PS. Even I felt the same (unable to successfully learn natural languages due to the several irregularities) and thus myself decided to go for toki pona first (because I already know a lot about it) and then Esperanto.

Answer (score 1):

The best one that I've seen is probably Esperanto. It has a relatively small vocabulary that makes up a great bulk of the words and there are different affixes that change the meanings of words. For example, *bo-* is used in front of any family member to make it '-in-law' (*boonklo, bopatro, bofrato, &c* are *uncle-in-law, father-in-law, brother-in-law*) The language is perfectly regular with no exceptions once you learn the quirks of the grammar. I see above in the comments that somebody said that they didn't like Esperanto but it doesn't look like it's the OP, so I'll leave the suggestion here anyway.

If you want minimalism is the goal, then I definitely suggest toki pona which has only has 120-125 words. There's a varation of that called toki ma which has closer to 300, but there's a lot of overlap with vocabulary.